# Find Branching factor of tree graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Imagine I have two numbers $m$ and $n$ now I can build tree graph with branching factor of n in this way: 
The root of tree is m, in the second level of three each node has value  $$k= \frac{m}{n+1}$$ and in the third level each node has value of $$k = \frac{k}{n+1}$$ and so on continue this process until the last level of tree which each node values is 1.
Now Given number of Ones which means leaf of tree and $m$ I want to find branching factor of three which means $n$ see picture below for more explanation
[image]

In this picture $m$ is $16$ and number of ones is $9$ as I said above in the second level of tree each node has value of $k= \frac{16}{3+1}$ which here is 4 and in the third level of tree each node is $k= \frac{4}{3+1}$ which here is 1 that is the last level of tree because each node value is 1 and the answer $n$ is $3$ branching factor of tree

Comment: Looks like it might be interesting but unfortunately I really don't understand most of your question. Are those two expressions meant to be the same? Are they actually the same value? How do you calculate $16$ etc.?

Comment: @Joffan Sorry for my terrible English, I edited my question and explained more about the question

Comment: Thanks for the updates, I will review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going down with each level you divide your number by the same factor, namely $n+1$. Going up you reverse this, which means you multiply by $n+1$.

This means that if $h$ is the height of the tree including leaves (i.e. your example has height 3) and you start with $1$, then $$m = (n+1)^{h-1} \cdot 1.$$

In your case that is $16 = 4^{3-1}$. Furthermore, with each level you get $n$ more nodes, thus the number of leaves is

$$l = n^{h-1},$$

in your case $9 = 3^{3-1}$. That makes two equations with two unknowns ($n$ and $h$). First we transform the second one into $$h-1 = \frac{\log l}{\log n}$$
and substitute into the first:
$$m = (n+1)^{\frac{\log l}{\log n}}$$
that is
$$\frac{\log m}{\log l} = \frac{\log (n+1)}{\log n}.$$
As $m > l > 1$ for the solution to exist (except some edge cases), we consider function $\frac{\log (x+1)}{\log x}$ for $x > 1$ where it is continuous, strictly decreasing and even convex. Thus, you can use any of the standard techniques to search for the solution.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Wow It's perfect thanks so much for such excellent answer